# google storage acl change on existing object

Tags: python, authentication, acl, google-cloud-storage

im having problems understanding how to put all the headers together to change an acl on an exixting object on google storage for developers. i need to do this manually without boto or other helper libs.

what i need to do is basically set an object from public to private and the other way around.

this is basically the example i found on [the developers guide](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/developer-guide.html#authorization)

```
PUT /paris.jpg?acl HTTP/1.1
Host: travel-maps.commondatastorage.googleapis.com
Date: Mon, 15 Feb  2008 21:30:39 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Authorization: GOOG1 GOOGTS7C7FUP3AIRVJTE:Y9gBLAEInIlFv5zlAm9ts=
x-goog-acl: private

<empty entity body>
```

what is not clear to me and where im stuck is how i build the signature. 
the signature is composed by:

```
Signature = Base64-Encoding-Of(HMAC-SHA1(UTF-8-Encoding-Of(YourGoogleStorageSecretKey, MessageToBeSigned)))
```

i dont know which header parts i should include, exclude, newlines.... to compose the MessageToBeSigned.
does anyone have a python sample code where he is doing something similar?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend using [the JSON api](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/) with Google's api client libraries, which make make authorization easier in a variety of language.

Second, I recommend [authenticating with OAuth](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth) instead of HMAC. This is much easier because you can just send your access token over HTTPS instead of figuring out how to sign a request. Every request is authenticated with something along the lines of:

```
Authorization: OAuth Bearer 1/2093840249809382402890948
```

That being said, take a look here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference/v1/developer-guidev1#authentication

MessageToBeSigned is defined as the UTF8 encoding of the canonical headers, extension headers and resource:

```
MessageToBeSigned = UTF-8-Encoding-Of(
    CanonicalHeaders +
    CanonicalExtensionHeaders +
    CanonicalResource)
```

The headers are:

```
CanonicalHeaders = HTTP-Verb + "\n" +
Content-MD5 + "\n" +
Content-Type + "\n" +
Date + "\n"
```

Etc...

If you generate the wrong message to sign Google will return the expected string to sign in the response body. So the easiest way to verify you are generating the right string to sign is to compare your string with the string Google expects.